# best way to extract meeting history data with Microsoft Graph

Tags: events, calendar, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

sorry I'm new to MS Graph. I'm working on a app to extract meeting history data for past hour/day/week/month for my company. I found there are APIs I can use:

- [List events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
- [List calendarView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
- [getSchedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

all 3 have different version under Users, Calendar and Groups,
which is the best to do the job?

I heard about delegated permission and application permission.
is delegated permssion good enough for me? or I have to ask for application permission?
one solution I heard: deletegated permission, create a normal account, share all meeting room account to this account. does this work for me?

Thanks
Wes

Comment: You need to understand the differences first:

List events - its used to retrieve a list of events in a given calendar.

List calendarview - using this you can get the occurrences, exceptions, and single instances of events in a calendar view defined by a time range, from the user's default calendar, or from some other calendar of the user's.

getschedule - you can get the free/busy availability information for a collection of users, distributions lists, or resources (rooms or equipment) for a specified time period.

Comment: Also you need to understand the differences between the delegated & application permission - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/developer-glossary#permissions. In short, if you want to access your calendar then go for Delegated, wherein if you want to access others calendar as well then go for application permission.

Comment: Moving to answer - as this can be useful to others as well. Consider upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the differences first: List events - its used to retrieve a list of events in a given calendar. List calendarview - using this you can get the occurrences, exceptions, and single instances of events in a calendar view defined by a time range, from the user's default calendar, or from some other calendar of the user's. getschedule - you can get the free/busy availability information for a collection of users, distributions lists, or resources (rooms or equipment) for a specified time period.

Also you need to understand the differences between the delegated & application permission - [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/developer-glossary#permissions). In short, if you want to access your calendar then go for Delegated, wherein if you want to access others calendar as well then go for application permission.