# calendarView work with shared meeting room account?

Tags: calendar, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-calendar

Since I start working on MSGraph to extract all the meeting history data. I asked [what's the best way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64281553/best-way-to-extract-meeting-history-data-with-microsoft-graph). Now I know:

- List events does not support parameter of date range, so I cannot use
  it.
- getSchedule has [bug of odata.nextLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64282993/getschedule-return-no-odata-nextlink), I already file
  ticket.
- Now I like to try calendarView. calendarView only related to the login account, e.g. I
  login as A, if meeting room account B have a meeting not related to
  A, then calendarView will not get it. so I'm thinking, if I share B
  to A, then I can use

  [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{accountB}/calendarView?startDateTime=..](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BaccountB%7D/calendarView?startDateTime=..).

  to get the data.

I tested it, but got error message:

```
{"code":"ErrorItemNotFound","message":"The specified object was not found in the store."}
```

what could be wrong?

Comment: If i want to access the shared mailbox using Microsoft graph, i would try this: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{Alex-userId | Alex-userPrincipalName}/calendar/events. Please note that the sharing permissions (Calendars.Read.Shared or Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared) allow you to read or write events in a shared or delegated calendar Before that i will make sure i have the enough permissions and follow the documentation - .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-shared-events-calendars

Comment: Let me move this to answer. So it can be useful to others. You may wish to upvote for it.

Answer (score 0):

If i want to access the shared mailbox using Microsoft graph, i would try this:

```html
GET graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users{Alex-userId | Alex-userPrincipalName}/calendar/events
```

Please note that the sharing permissions (Calendars.Read.Shared or Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared) allow you to read or write events in a shared or delegated calendar. Before that i will make sure i have the enough permissions and follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-shared-events-calendars).